# how to set the cell value in dynamic datagrid in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got row id and column id

```
dataGrid2.Items[row].Cells[column].Text = "text";
row = row index;
column = column index;
```

Comment: you mean the current cell selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [it is not working, what do I do dataGrid2.Items\[row\] .Cells\[column\] .Text = "text";](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109372/it-is-not-working-what-do-i-do-datagrid2-itemsrow-cellscolumn-text-tex)

Comment: yes,i want get current cell value and next cell value after i add two cell value then set this value to another next cell in datagrid ( Dynamic)in wpf using c#

Answer (score 0):

you can simply update the value of the underlying datasource and its show in your datagrid. you dont need any index stuff

Comment: i want get current cell value and next cell value after i add two cell value then set this value to another next cell in datagrid ( Dynamic)in wpf using c#