# it is not working, what do I do dataGrid2.Items[row] .Cells[column] .Text = "text";

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a row, column id.

This statement is not working, what do I do?

```
dataGrid2.Items[row] .Cells[column] .Text = "text";
```

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: why put second question with identical content? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106708/how-to-set-the-cell-value-in-dynamic-datagrid-in-wpf-using-c-sharp

Comment: check the following link http://techiethings.blogspot.in/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataGrid2.Rows[row][column].Value = "text";
```

Comment: there is no `Rows` in WPF `DataGrid`

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i want get current cell value and next cell value after i add two cell value then set this value to another next cell in datagrid ( Dynamic)in wpf using c#